# setMassactionIdField keep selecting entity_id instead of custom id field

Tags: magento-1.9, module

I'm having this weird problem and I can't find the solution for this anywhere from google. I want to add Massaction column for my custom module grid. I think my code is correct.

```
protected function _prepareMassaction()
    {
        $this->setMassactionIdField('paperprice_id');
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('paperprice');
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('delete', array(
            'label' => $this->_getHelper()->__('Delete'),
            'url' => $this->getUrl('*/*/massDelete'),
            'confirm' => $this->_getHelper()->__('Are you sure?')
        ));

        return $this;
    }
```

Unfortunately, it thrown error saying that 'entity_id not found'. Whereby im getting the collection from custom table that not have any 'entity_id' column.

```
a:5:{i:0;s:178:"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'main_table.entity_id' in 'field list', query was: SELECT `main_table`.`entity_id` FROM `pb_componentprice` AS `main_table`";i:1;s:5320:"#0 /var/www/magento/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
```

What is the reason? I believe it suppose to select 'paperprice_id' instead if 'entity_id'.

Comment: how is your `_prepareCollection()`?

Comment: Add your grid full code as well as massDelete action code here may be it make sense

Comment: setMassactionIdField seems to default to the collection init id value

Answer (score 2):

Just add this line in your *_prepareCollection()* function.

```
$this->getColumn('massaction')->setUseIndex(true);
```

The column sent in *setMassactionIdField* function is overriden if the collection used for the grid has a primary key, unless we set the above mentioned flag true for massaction column.